# Ошибка "Не найден указанный модуль" после преобразования в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, pywin32

В скрипте используется библиотека `pywin32`, установленная только что командой `pip install pywin32`
При запуске скрипта через `python script.py`код отлично выполняется. Однако конечной целью является преобразование скрипта в исполняемый файл формата .exe

После использования команды `pyinstaller -F "msg.py"` получился готовый файл **msg.exe**, однако уже при его запуске скрипт завершает работу с ошибкой **ImportError**

**Вывод:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "msg.py", line 4, in <module>
      import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: Не найден указанный модуль. 
[11004] Failed to execute script msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забавно, но помогло в итоге добавление всего одной строки! Спасибо всем, кто помогал разобраться в проблеме. Идею решения взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718414/pyinstaller-does-not-recognize-downloaded-pywin32).

```
import pywintypes
```

Answer (score 2):

Выдержка ответов [отсюда](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1840):

1. Попробуйте сделать ещё `pip install pypiwin32`, не факт, что поможет, но всё же.
2. Установите Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. Судя по ответам, многим помогло.

Comment: В данный момент установлены все версии Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package от 2005 до 2019 года. К сожалению, действия не помогли(

win32api использую для захвата закрытия окна консоли, может быть есть другие методы без этой библиотеки? 

`win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)`